# AngularJS Manually Bootstrapping a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My html...

```
<body id="main">
  {{pageName}}
</body>
```

My JS:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('myController', function($scope){
   console.log('init');
   $scope.pageName = 'My page';
});

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
   angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('main'), ['myApp']);
});
```

My Resulting HTML:

`{{pageName}}` instead of 'My Page'

I can do this

```
<body id="main" ng-controller="myController">
</body>
```

and it will start working. But, what is the point. Why do I necessarily have to use `ng-controller` ?

I hope I have made myself clear. Hoping someone would respond to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that you are setting pageName in `myController` but the div cannot use it as the controller is neither defined on it or its parent.

`pageName` should be set on $rootScope to make it work. You can define that at the run block of module like

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.pageName='My Page';
});
```

This run block runs after angular has bootstrapped the application. See here
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module